# PHP multi curl - return unknown value

Tags: php, curl

I want to user curl for login to other websites. I use curl multi threading for it.

**code 1:**

```
<?php
$ch1 = curl_init();
$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $post);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $post2)
$mh = curl_multi_init();
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);
$active = null;
do {
  $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        do {
           $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}
?>
```

**code 2 :**

```
<?php
$mh = curl_multi_init();
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{   
    $key = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($key, CURLOPT_URL, $value["url"]);
    curl_setopt($key, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $value[$key]);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$key);

}
$active = null;
do {
   $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
    }
}
?>
```

Code 1 can return me result that i want but not very dynamic. Code 2 just return me ‹‹. Anyone can explain to me why like this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide an example of `$data` you are using in the second example. The first loop there makes no sense for me:

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) //assuming $key here is a scalar
{   
    $key = curl_init();   // after this line $key is a resource or false
    curl_setopt($key, CURLOPT_URL, $value["url"]);
    curl_setopt($key, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $value[$key]); // likely $value[$key] is empty, and there is a notice in the log 
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$key);
}
```

Apart from that, you probably want to close handlers after the final loop, and output some results. I don't see at which point *Code 2 just return* anything.